# What is the purpose Fluent NHiberate's KeyUpdate method? 

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a collection mapped as a query only property following [Ayende's example](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/10/nhibernate-ndash-query-only-properties.aspx). My mapping is:

```
HasMany<Employee>(Reveal.Member<Company>("_employees")).Access.None();
```

This worked fine, except when I load a Company the foreign key Employee.CompanyId is updated to null. This occurs even if I don't update Company and the generated SQL only includes the CompanyId in the update list even though I have not mapped Employee to update changed properties only.

I tried using `NoOp` (they're synonyms I think) and declaring the employees collection as a public property instead of a private field. I was finally able to fix it by changing the mapping to:

HasMany(Reveal.Member("_employees")).Access.None().Not.KeyUpdate();

What is the purpose of KeyUpdate and what is the equivalent XML mapping? Why is it needed for a query only property? My assumption was that setting access to none or noop would prevent any changes.

Comment: According to http://fluentnhibernate.org/api/FluentNHibernate.Mapping/OneToManyPart`1.htm (sorry, the link doesn't come through with `\``), it designates that the key can be updated. I'm not sure how that has anything to do with what you're seeing, though.

Comment: This is still a "bug" in NH 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jamie

You can generate the hbms from your AutoPersistenceModel and have a look at the xml if you are still interested. Just something like

```
model.CompileMappings(); 
model.WriteMappingsTo(outputDir);
```

As an aside, have you had a look yet @ [ConfOrm](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/02/conform-nhibernate-un-mapping.html). I suspect this will gain increased traction given the dev, but haven't spent much time with it yet.

HTH,
Berryl

Comment: How does this answer what the purpose is for Fluent NHibernate's KeyUpdate method?